# java - FATAL EXCEPTION: main when calling method from another class

Tags: java, android, exception

I downloaded a Java Class named DrawingView from GitHub and I added it to my layout in xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/background_default_xhdpi"
    android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="false"
    android:stretchColumns="2"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/botonatras"
            android:src="@drawable/back_button"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/preguntapractica"
            android:id="@+id/preguntapractica"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:lines="4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_span="2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/botontp"
            android:src="@drawable/back_button"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/botonborrar"
            android:src="@drawable/boton_borrar"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="top|right"
            android:layout_span="2" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/frameLayoutPizarra"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_span="3">

            <es.sd.ftop.DrawingView
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:id="@+id/drawing"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
            </FrameLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="0">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/botonajustes"
            android:src="@drawable/settings"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/respuestapractica"
            android:id="@+id/respuestapractica"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:lines="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="40dp"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:singleLine="false" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/botonvalidarcomprobar"
            android:src="@drawable/boton_comprobar"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Then, when I try to clean the Canvas by:

```
public void cleanUp(){
    m_Canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    // It fails, even with no code here
}
```

and I call that method from practicalibre.java, I get FATAL EXCEPTION: main when I click on that button:

```
ImageButton botonborrar = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.botonborrar);
botonborrar.setColorFilter(Color.argb(255,252,59,57));

final DrawingView drawingView = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);
botonborrar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        drawingView.cleanUp();
    }
});
```

And the error:

```
08-24 18:02:34.972    7665-7665/es.sd.ftop E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at es.sd.ftop.FTOP_practicalibre$1.onClick(FTOP_practicalibre.java:58)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4222)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17337)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Does anybody know how to solve it? Thanks :)

Comment: Where is `cleanUp()` defined?

Comment: In DrawingView class

Comment: I don't see `id/botonborrar` in the layout, is it in the same layout with  `id/drawing`?

Comment: Nope, the FrameLayout is inside a TableRow, where is located botonborrar

Comment: Building on @AntonSavin I don't see either id's... `R.id.botonborrar` or `R.id.drawing`. Just as you added the id to the FrameLayout, you'll need to do so for the ImageButton and the Drawing if you're going to reference them via R

Comment: I think now it's better shown ;-)

Comment: Anyway, have you checked that after the line `final DrawingView drawingView = (DrawingView)findViewById(R.id.drawing);` drawingView is not null?

Comment: I have just done it, and it's null... How can I solve it? Thanks

Comment: Are you running `findViewById` from `onCreate()` method of your Activity? Please provide some surrounding code.